# Apache2 Ubuntu config showing google search

Tags: linux, apache, laravel, ubuntu, apache2

I have configured my fresh installed apache. When I am trying to put `local.myproject` in the browser it starts searching on google. Like the link was not working. Could somebody please tell me what happens? I tried to restart apache and reload the conf files.

sites-availabe/myproject.conf:

```
ServerName local.myproject
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
DocumentRoot /home/programmer/NetBeansProjects/myproject/public
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_1.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_1.log combined

  <Directory /home/programmer/NetBeansProjects/myproject/public>
            Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   computer
127.0.0.1   local.myproject
```

Comment: May be the issue with reloading apache. Try `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload`

Comment: Reset cache of your browser.

Comment: After restarting the system the link shows me apache info page instead of my projects index...

Comment: Did you do the command `sudo a2ensite myproject.conf`?

Answer (score 0):

Restart your Apache server by:
`sudo service apache2 restart`

OR
Check error log:
`ls /var/log/apache2/error-YOURDOMAINNAME.log`

You can check what you missed by check every steps [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts).